# Я хочу в рамку поместить весь блок,но помещается только часть. В чем причина?

Tags: html, css

В рамку не помещается весь блок почему-то, а всего лишь 2 строчки.

```css
BODY {
  background-color: #e6d3ff
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #460ee0;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

div.table {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  border: 5px dotted #0000b9;
}

p.table {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  color: #170076;
}

.pharagraph {
  text-indent: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.paragraph_top {
  color: red;
  margin: 0px;
}

.paragraph_bottom {
  color: #0000b9;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0 0 5 0px;
}

p.signature {
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 180px;
}

.table2 {
  border: 5px double gold;
}
```

```html
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <title>Стили шрифта и текста</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <h1>Электронная почта</h1>
  <p class="pharagraph">
    <B>Отправить электронное письмо может любой абонент сети, если он знает нужный электронный адрес. Пример электронного адреса: <I>somov@pgu.perm.ru</I>. Он состоит из следующих частей:</B>
  </p>
  <div class="table">
    <p class="table">Страна<br>ru<br>(Россия)</p>
    <p class="table">Город<br>perm<br>(Пермь)</p>
    <p class="table">Имя сервера<br>pgu<br>(ПГУ)</p>
    <p class="table">Имя почт. ящика<br>somov<br>(Сомов)</p>
  </div>
  <p class="pharagraph">
    <B>В целом электронное письмо состоит из "конверта" и текста. Обычно на "конверте" записывается адрес получателя, адрес отправителя и краткая информация о назначении письма:</B>
  </p>
  <div class="table2">
    <p class="paragraph_top">Куда: Frolov@yandex.ru</p>
    <p class="paragraph_top">Откуда: somov@pgu.perm.ru</p>
    <p class="paragraph_top">Поздравление</p>
    <p class="paragraph_bottom">Поздравляю Вас с Днем рождения.<br>Желаю Вам счастья и здоровья.</p>
    <p class="signature">Р. Сомов</p>
  </div>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте убрать в css стилях строчку `position: fixed;` у класса `.paragraph_bottom`, такой результат вам нужен?

Comment: да, только как текст сделать по середине блока?

Comment: Если вы хотите весь текст выровнять по центру (и красный и синий), добавьте с таблицу стилей класса `.table2` строчку `text-align: center;` а у класса `.paragraph_bottom` можете её убрать.

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы эта рамка было сразу после текста, но и этот блок был по середине